# Use different clock for SPI receive and send data on RPI4B

Tags: spi

Has anyone here ever used two different clocks to synchronize sent and received data via SPI ? By that I mean, using a PIN clock1 for transmission and a PIN clock2 for reception.

I don't know if it is faisable with Rasberry pi 4b ?

This makes it possible to double transmission speeds with the SPI protocol using LVDS technology.

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pi's SPI hardware does not have that ability (it is SPI after all).